# Replace specific letters in a list with other letters

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a  list that looks like this:

```
foo = ["z", "q", "t", "a", "p", "m", "n", "b", "c", "w", "l", "d", "f", "h",
       "y", "e", "j", "k", "g", "i", "o", "r", "u", "s", "v", "x"]
```

and i have another list that looks like this:

```
bar = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "m", "y", "n", "a", "m", "e", "i", "s", "r",
       "e", "a", "l", "l", "y", "l", "o", "n", "g", "a", "n", "d"]
```

what i want to do is use the first element of foo, and replace the first element of bar with it, and so that the first element of foo is now always worth `"h"`, so if `"h"` ever comes up in bar again, `"z"` (the first element of foo) is automatically put in. the second element of foo is then subbed in for the second element of bar (unless it's `"h"`) and then second element then becomes `"e"`, and so on until the entirety or bar has been encrypted using foo for the letters. and then print the new bar but with the letters changed from the encrypton process.

Comment: is the question simply about how to implement a substitution cipher in python? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher

Comment: RanRag, ive only tried doing foo[0] = bar[0] but that doesnt work because if there's another "h" for example, it just overwrites it.

Comment: and shin, i know what it is, im struggling to implement it into python

Comment: I thought I understood what you were asking, but on reading it again it's really unclear. You may want to rephrase the last paragraph.

Comment: Python has a built-in for this, have a look at [translate](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple, actually:

```
new_string = ''

for every letter in your string:
  new_string = new_string + bar[index of the "letter" in foo]
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out the appropriate Python functions, as you'd benefit from learning how to do it by yourself.

Comment: I read over the OPs question again, and it's not clear that this will do it. It sounds like letters are being replaced from both `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Yes it is not as simple as this.

Comment: Don't reinvent the python standard library. Look into string.maketrans combined with string.translate for a pythonic way of accomplishing this.

Comment: @JosefAssad: There's a reason I wrote out the code in pseudo-code, not in Python. There are ways to make it more compact at the cost of learning how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with Blender's approach, here's another way to do it.

```
new_string = ''
cipher = dict(zip(foo,bar))
for every_letter in your_string: 
    # use more python magic here
```

If you're going to use python you should learn about [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).